# as3 inherited variables

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, inheritance, super

I have a base class "Vehicle" and a derived class "Car".

```
package Game
{

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public var myVar = "vehicle";

        public function Vehicle()
        {
            trace("vehicle: " + myVar);
            DoSomethingWithMyVar();
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
package Game
{

    public class Car extends Vehicle
    {

        public function Car()
        {
            trace("car pre: " + myVar);
            myVar = "car";
            trace("car post: " + myVar);
            super();
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, I want to set a vehicle property in Car's constructor, call Vehicle's constructor with super() and have Vehicle do something based on myVar.  But this is the output i get:

```
car pre: null
car post: car
vehicle: vehicle
```

Why does myVar not keep the value of "car" when the base class constructor is called?  How am I supposed to implement this correctly?

Comment: Can you share a bit more about the actual goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable initialization is in the super class.  It won't be initialized until you actually call `super();`.  This is why you should always call `super()` before doing anything else in the constructor.  In fact, in some other languages, like Java, calls to `super()` are only allowed as the first statement within subclass constructors.

However, you should consider using an initialization parameter in your constructor instead of setting the value in the declaration - it is the more elegant and maintainable way of doing what you intend to do.

```
package game
{   
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public var myVar: String;

        public function Vehicle ( type:String = "vehicle" ) 
                             // new Vehicle() traces "vehicle"
        {
            trace("vehicle: " + type);
            myVar = type;
            doSomethingWithMyVar();
        }
    }
}
```

resp.

```
public function Car ( type: String = "car" )
                             // new Car() traces "car"
{
    super( type );
}
```

plus, you can always call `new Car("Porsche");`, or something like that ;)

P.S. On a side note: Naming conventions in ActionScript recommend using names starting with a lower case letter for both packages and methods.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I had the super() at the end rather than at the beginning was because of the initialization stuff.  I will separate the initialization routine from the constructor.

I wasn't aware of the naming convention (although I should have realized that all existing methods are lowercase...).  Thanks again!